# How does the Analytical badge work?

Tags: support, badges, analytical-badge

> **As of June 2013, this badge [is no longer awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183243/152859) as the FAQ has been changed to the Help Center all across the network**

I've just seen this new badge on Stack Overflow, how does it work?

Is it awarded when I've read all section of the FAQ? I've done that but did not earn the badge.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Some of the sections are collapsed.  You need to expand all of the sections in the table of contents, which you can do by clicking on the headers of the sections, or by using the table of contents on the right sidebar.

Comment: I'm pretty sure to have done that. I'm gonna try again.

Comment: @Fabio Check your dropdown (hover over username), then, as this is one of those badges for which the banner announcement is suppressed, AFAICT.

Comment: Nope, I got the banner announcement (on [tex.se])

Comment: @don I didn't get a banner on either SO or Meta.  Perhaps it varies by site and/or the badge count of the user, then.

Comment: @Jonsca got it...

Comment: @Fabio Great! You may now add "Analyst" after you title.

Comment: It might have something to do with these mysterious _deploys_ or _rebuilds_? While I managed to get the badge on [tex.se] and [meta.tex.se], I can't seem to get it here.

Comment: Now I got it, too. Crazy world. Long live the Analysts.

Comment: @jonska why should I add Analyst in the title? Is this badge named differently in other SE sites?

Comment: @Fabio Oh, sorry, I was kidding -- I meant,since you earned it, add it after your job title on your business card.

Comment: I never got the bar on SO or Meta.

Comment: I left and came back, and it was awarded with the bar.

Comment: Well, it seems I have got my Analytical badge yet, though I have expand and carefully read all FAQ.

Comment: @YCFlame At first, I tried clicking on each section in the floating nav menu to the right, but to no avail. Then I clicked through again, except this time I waited for the orange to completely fade out (takes maybe 4 or 5 seconds). After clicking all of them that way, I got the badge.

Comment: Like some of you guys for me it only appears when hovered over the username and not in the actual badges page. Ta

Comment: I first clicked all the links on the side really quickly. 30 minutes later I clicked expand all and waited until the badge was awarded. Took about 15 minutes. Did this on MSO and C.SE. On main SO I only clicked the links on the side really quickly. Still awarded. Using Chrome 26 on Win 7.

Comment: @fredsbend If you think that information will be pertinent to others, don't hesitate to separate it out into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox I found that if I return to the FAQ page or refresh, some of the sections that I thought I'd visited already weren't darkened so I opened them again.  After a couple times they were all dark (except "What if I need more help?") and then I got the badge.

Comment: you should probably submit a bug about this rather than posting it here

Comment: I first clicked all the links on the side really quickly. 30 minutes later I clicked expand all and waited until the badge was awarded. Took about 15 minutes. Did this on MSO and C.SE. On main SO I only clicked the links on the side really quickly. Still awarded. Using Chrome 26 on Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

I first clicked all the links on the side really quickly. 30 minutes later I clicked expand all and waited until the badge was awarded. Took about 15 minutes. Did this on MSO and C.SE. On main SO I only clicked the links on the side really quickly. Still awarded. Using Chrome 26 on Win 7.