# "Analytical" badge not awarded

Tags: discussion, badges, analytical-badge

I just saw that the "Analytical" badge is awarded to those who read all the sections of FAQ. I am pretty sure that I read all the sections of FAQ, but I did not see analytical badge on my profile.

From [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103797/analytical-badge) post, I learned nothing.

I also tried using "expand all" option. (Does "expand all" counted as visiting all posts?). Can an administrator confirm what links in the FAQ I am missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The badge is not awarded immediately after you view every section. First, verify you have viewed all of every section (some sections have a link at the bottom where you click to view more content), and then wait a while. I've gotten the badge on a couple SE sites, and the quickest I've gotten it is about a minute later, and the longest was a few hours (I left the site and came back a couple hours later and it was there).

**Update:**
For *some* information about how badges are awarded, see these [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/898/167443) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/898/167443).

Comment: got the badge...I think "expand all" worked.

Comment: Can you also explain the reason behind this delay of upto hours?

Comment: (Note: This is only my understanding. Can someone definitively confirm this?) Most badges are awarded by scripts that run every so often to check to see if users have earned them. When you actually *look* at the FAQ, it does nothing to check if you have earned the badge. Once the scripts time interval is up, it runs and checks who has viewed all sections and does not have the badge, and awards it to them. The gap in time comes from visiting every section when the script is not scheduled to run for a while.

Comment: This particular badge is usually awarded fairly soon after its completion. But I think it's a silent badge (you won't get notification). @hrishikeshp19: Yes, you actually have to click expand for every single section. It should only take maybe 15 minutes tops after that for the badge to appear.

Comment: I believe I have gotten a notification for it (I may be mistaken), but I don't think I've gotten it every time (occasionally awarded alongside other badges)