# Analytical: How does it exactly work?

Tags: support, badges, analytical-badge

I've learned that to be awarded with an 'Analytical' badge, you need to visit all sections of the FAQ. Well, I'm pretty sure I did visit all sections in there. But what I can't seem to understand is that, how come I haven't earned the badge yet?

Did I just miss something?

Comment: Did you expand and read them all?

Comment: Yes, I did. I even visited all the other available links underneath every discussion.

Comment: And how long ago was that? You should give the job some time, those jobs aren't run every five minutes.

Comment: Yeah...I guess that might be the issue. Thanks for responding, though! :)

Comment: The FAQ is supposed to be read, not to get a badge for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Analytical badge work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103797/how-does-the-analytical-badge-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've noticed that if you go through clicking them too fast, it doesn't work. What I normally do is click one (the side menu at the right) and wait for the fadey thing to finish (pure white background) before moving to the next one.

The badge is also not normally awarded immediately, but fairly soon after completing the requirements. Make sure you don't skip any.

Comment: I guess so... they must have put a timer to check whether the user is actually reading through every line in the FAQ... thanks!

Comment: I first clicked all the links on the side really quickly. 30 minutes later I clicked expand all and waited until the badge was awarded. Took about 15 minutes. Did this on MSO and C.SE. On main SO I only clicked the links on the side really quickly. Still awarded. Using Chrome 26 on Win 7.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read all of it. This includes expanding every expandable section as well.

If you have done that and haven't gotten the badge yet, you just need to wait. It's not awarded instantly.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to make new user aware of the Frequently Ask Questions, if you read carefully each section you would not face this issue and many others issues may hit you in future, so kindly take some time and read each section.

Analytical badge is to encourage to read the FAQ sections, if you skip or quickly switch one of its section it might not get awarded.